# Solr not displaying all indexed data

Tags: php, mysql, yii, solr

I am having issues with solr displaying all indexed data.  My application queries a remote database using their API to pull all new data into a MySQL database.  The MySQL database currently shows 143 records.

We then run a script to update the Solr index and it shows 143 records updated and 0 removed.

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
</lst>
<lst name="initArgs">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">solr-data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">full-import</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">573</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">1235</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2015-04-16 11:22:14</str>
<str name="">
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 143 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
</str>
<str name="Committed">2015-04-16 11:22:15</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">143</str>
<str name="Time taken">0:0:0.694</str>
</lst>
<str name="WARNING">
This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.
</str>
</response>
```

When running a query for all records, Solr is only displaying 96 of the 143 records.

I am stumped at this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Garry

Comment: This looks like 143 documents went in, but when you look at the Solr admin page does it say you have 143 documents or 96?

Comment: try adding '&rows=150' to your query

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not committing the indexed data which sometimes cause these kinds of issues. Commit after indexing or better update your SOLR config to use autocommit ([here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#Update_Handler_Section)).